# Store score in a variable after an event

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

**Desirable result:** After the user choose an answer, I want to modify `score` variable in:
`score += 1` if the answer is right either not changing at all if the answer is wrong.
**Current result:** For every choice user is making, the score remains the same: `0`.

First, I store the paragraph that will be changed in `question_paragraph` and the button that will be clicked by user in `next_button`. Also, I stored the value(I put the attribute `value` on every input using the array notation - 0 first, 1 second etc.) in `user_answer`.

```
var question_paragraph = document.getElementById('question');
var next_button = document.getElementById('next');
var i = 0;
var user_answer = getCheckedValue(document.getElementsByName('choice'));
var y = 0;
var score = 0;
```

The `getCheckedValue` function will return the `value` attribute of my input if exists.

```
function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
    var radioLength = radioObj.length;
    for(var z = 0; z < radioLength; z++) {
        if(radioObj[z].checked) {
            return radioObj[z].value;
        }
    }
    return "Error!";
}
```

Here is the **problem**. The function works fine, except the isolated area. `allQuestion` is my object where I stored the questions, the possible answers and the right answer, `correctAnswer`(I don't included it here but works correctly). I put a conditional statement to increase `y` and code>score with one if the `allQuestions[y].correctAnswer` is qual with the value of the `user_choice`.

```
function changeQuestion() {

    //PROBLEM
    if(allQuestions[y].correctAnswer == user_answer){
    score += 1;
    y++;
    } else{y++;}  
    //PROBLEM



    i = (i < allQuestions.length) ? (i + 1) : 0;
    if (i == allQuestions.length) {
        i = 0;
        return question_paragraph.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(allQuestions[0].question), question_paragraph.firstChild);
    }
    var newNode = document.createTextNode(allQuestions[i].question);
    console.log(score);
    return question_paragraph.replaceChild(newNode, question_paragraph.firstChild);
}
```

Finnaly, I called the `addHandler` function.

```
function addHandler(name, type, handler){
    if (name.addEventListener){
        name.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else if (name.attachEvent){
        name.attachEvent("on" + type, handler);
    } else {
        name["on" + type] = handler;
    }
}

addHandler(next_button, 'click', changeQuestion);
```

Comment: shouldnt you count up y++; everytime changeQuestion() is called ?

Comment: @johnSmith it does that; there's a `y++` on both parts of the conditional.

Comment: How do you know that it's ever even *trying* to increment `score`?  Have you put a `console.log()` inside the `if` ?

Comment: i modified, still not working.

Comment: Also, in the code you posted there's only one call to `getCheckedValue()`.  After the question changes, don't you have to call it again to get the new answer?

Comment: thanks man, i edited in if statement variable <code>user_answer</code> with <code>getCheckedValue(document.getElementsByName('choice')))</code> and now works .

Answer (score 0):

Well, something just appears to be funny here so far. First of all, I don't see any initialization to the variable y. If y is a global variable that is retaining its value, then maybe there is an issue with your object: allQuestions{}. Could you provide the code for building your object allQuestions{}? Without it, I don't think that I could fully answer this question, but I believe that is where your problem lies.

Oops, this was supposed to be a comment, not an answer, sorry...

Comment: i made the initialization,look at the first block.The problem was the user_answer variable, because the 'getCheckedValue' will be called only once.